# Showing Byte Image in repeater

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, image, repeater

I want to some images in asp repeater which comes from databas image table.

HTML

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rpt_" runat="server">                       
   <ItemTemplate>
     <li>
<img src="<%="data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("Photo")) %>" alt="" />
     </li>
   </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

C#

```
private void Load_()
{
    ClassDo class_ = new ClassDo;
    DataTable dt = class_.Ann().Tables[0];
    rpt_.DataSource = dt;
    rpt_.DataBind();
}
```

These are my codes, and get me error I cannot show images.
HTML

```
<img alt="" src="<%="data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(Class_._image) %>" />
```

C#

```
Class_._image = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Photo"];
```

It works like that somewhere else, but with repeater I cannot read it with `Eval`.

Is there any working way to show images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this?

Create a function

```
public string GetImage(object img)
{
   return "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])img);
}
```

Then change your declaration like this

```
<asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# GetImage(Eval("Photo")) %>' />
```